# In which order should I play the Borderlands series?

Tags: borderlands-series

I recently just beat Borderlands 1. There are a couple more missions left, but now I'm left wondering which Borderlands is next?

I own Borderlands 2 but now the Pre-Sequel is out and apparently that is supposed to be set before Borderlands 2?

If that's the case, what is the canonical order to play the Borderlands series?

Comment: Edited and voted to reopen based on [the meta question here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10727/28182)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would heavily recommend playing them in **release order**, with Borderlands 2 before the Pre-Sequel, even though most of the events in the Pre-sequel take place before Borderlands 2 (as it's told as a flashback)

- Borderlands
- Borderlands 2
- Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel
- Tales from the Borderlands
- Borderlands 3

Comment: In practice, *Tales from the Borderlands* is not very heavily connected to most of the other stuff. Although it does have some ties to *Pre-Sequel* and *2*, you can certainly play it without experiencing either of those (but it might spoil them, depending on how seriously you take "spoilers" for a comedy series). Since its play style is very different from the other games, some people might not be bothered by the spoilers (because they do not plan to play the other games anyway).